# Add import within a snippet - VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am writing a code snippet in Visual Studio Code, and I need that the snippet will import libraries if they are not already imported.

A simple example: I want to create a snippet in Java that will create a new `Scanner` and close it:

```
    "Scanner": {
    "prefix": "scanner",
    "body": [
        "Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);",
        "scanner.close();"]
    }
```

I need that if the code doesn't contain an import for `java.util.Scanner` it will be imported (as part of the snippet).

How can I do it?